# "mute" command gives random output

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
if(command === "mute"){
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (target) {

        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            return message.reply("Unauthorized");
        }
        let muted = client.settings.get(message.guild.id, 'mute')
        
        let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === muted);
        
        let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

        let rolelist = memberTarget.roles.cache
            .map(r => r)

        if (!args[1]) {
          
            memberTarget.roles.remove(rolelist);
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted`);
            return
        }
        memberTarget.roles.remove(rolelist);
        memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole);
        message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> will be muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`);

        setTimeout(function () {
            memberTarget.roles.add(rolelist);
            memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole);
        }, ms(args[1]));
        
    } else {
        message.channel.send('User not found!');
    }
```

So I have this mute command which removes all your roles, gives you the `muteRole`, when time is up, it gives back your previous roles and removes the `muteRole`. The problem I'm having is that it sometimes removes all your roles and doesn't give you the `muteRole`, other times it doesn't remove the `muteRole` when the time is up. Sometimes it removes all your roles and doesn't give you the
`muteRole` and when the times up it doesn't give your roles back...

Basically the outcome is always random. So my question is how do I make it consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods [`.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) and [`.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you should try using `await` / `.then()`.

If you do it with this, the next `function` or `.then()` will **not** be executed **until** the `promise` is **completely processed**.

Example:

```js
memberTarget.roles.remove(rolelist)
   .then(() => memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole))
   .then(() => message.channel.send('some message'));
```

Now you're nearly finished. The last thing you need is the `.catch()` block, because if the code above fails / throws an error you should `catch` that:

```
.catch(err => console.log(`An error occured: ${err}`))
```

**Final result:**

```js
memberTarget.roles.remove(rolelist)
   .then(() => memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole))
   .then(() => message.channel.send('some message'))
   .catch(err => console.log(`An error occured: ${err}`));
```

---

#### References

- [GuildMemberRoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) (Discord.js)
- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Handle `promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: i just tried that and after some testing, its still random...

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log()` to check, if the code is executed in the right order?

Comment: @Toasty you're misusing promises. For example, `.then(memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole))` is *not* going to wait to add the role, it will wait to execute a function that `GuildMemberRoleManager#add()` returns. It should be `.then(() => memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole))`, and this applies to then other `.then`s as well

Comment: @Lioness100 Thanks for the advice. Totally forgot that

Comment: @LifesGood Lioness has pointed out an error in my answer. I have now improved it. Try this

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, had to take care of something. I tried this and it worked, thanks a lot guys :)